# Getting data-id in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have `$display` variable passed:

```
 echo json_encode(array('status' => TRUE,  'display'=>$display)); die;
```

jQuery and AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data)
            {
                var res = $.parseJSON(data);
                if(res.status == true)
                {   var results='';         
                    if(res.display[i].type=='1')
                    {   
                        var b="Business";
                    }
                    if(res.display[i].type=='2')
                    {
                        var b="Economy";
                    }
                    for(var i=0;  i<res.display.length;  i++) 
                    {    
                        results +='<tr><td>'+(i+1)+'</td><td>'+res.display[i].name+'</td><td>'+b+'</td><td>'+res.display[i].seat+'</td><td>'+res.display[i].date_booked+'</td><td></td><td><a href="" class="remove" data-id='+res.display[i].id+'>Cancel ticket</a></td></tr>'
                     }
                }
```

`res.display[i].date_booked`,`res.display[i].seat`, `res.display[i].name` are fine but what is wrong with `data-id='+res.display[i].id+'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the quotes:

```
// Note the `a` tag's `data-id` is changed from:
//   data-id='+res.display[i].id+'>
// to
//   data-id="'+res.display[i].id+'">
results += '<tr>' + 
             '<td>'+(i+1)+'</td>' +
             '<td>'+res.display[i].name+'</td>' +
             '<td>'+b+'</td>' +
             '<td>'+res.display[i].seat+'</td>' +
             '<td>'+res.display[i].date_booked+'</td>' +
             '<td></td>' +
             '<td><a href="" class="remove" data-id="'+res.display[i].id+'">Cancel ticket</a></td>' +
           '</tr>';
```

Can I suggest you format your code as follows? So it's more readable:

```
$.ajax({
  type: frm.attr('method'),
  url: frm.attr('action'),
  data: frm.serialize(),
  success: function (data) {
    var res = $.parseJSON(data);

    if (!res.status) return;

    var results = '';
    for (var i = 0;  i < res.display.length;  i++) {    
      results += '<tr>' + 
             '<td>'+(i+1)+'</td>' +
             '<td>'+res.display[i].name+'</td>' +
             '<td>'+b+'</td>' +
             '<td>'+res.display[i].seat+'</td>' +
             '<td>'+res.display[i].date_booked+'</td>' +
             '<td></td>' +
             '<td><a href="" class="remove" data-id="'+res.display[i].id+'">Cancel ticket</a></td>' +
           '</tr>';
    }
  }
});
```